# How to achieve multiple aggregation as select sum(sal), avg(score), empId form Employee in Cloudant?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

How to implement below query in Cloudant?

```
SELECT companyId, AVG(score), SUM(sal), dept 
FROM employee 
WHERE ((joiningdate = ?) 
  AND (empid IS NOT NULL)) 
GROUP BY empId, companyId, dept
```

For single aggregation I can define the attribute in as value in my emit statement for example if I want to get sum of sal only my emit would be like `emit([doc.companyId, doc.score,doc.dept], doc.sal)` and my reduce would return sum of doc.sal.

But now in my case, I have to apply aggregation on two fields. How we can achieve this in Cloudant?

Answer (score 0):

you may try to define a custom Reduce function.

for example, if your Map function was similar to this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.companyId) {
    emit([doc.companyId, doc.dept], {"score": doc.score, "sal": doc.sal});
  }
}
```

then your Reduce function could be something like this:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  sal = sum(values.map(function (v) {return v.sal}));
  score = sum(values.map(function (v) {return v.score})) / values.length;

  return {"score": score, "sal": sal};
}
```